# Remove a line if count of delimiter is not equal to header

Tags: python, shell, awk, text-processing

I want to write a utility to remove lines from a DELIMITED file if count of DELIMITER character is not equal to header count.

For example if file is like this

```
NAME|ADDRESS|PHONE
Jack|SA|123|aaa|aaaa
JOHN|New York|111-222-3333
Jane|New Jer
```

I want below output

```
NAME|ADDRESS|PHONE
JOHN|New York|111-222-3333
```

Can anyone please help me how to achieve this in shell script? It would be great if I could do it using python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk -F\| 'NR==1{n=NF}NF==n' File
```

Set `|` as the delimiter. Save the count of fields (`NF`) present in the first line (`NR==1`) to variable `n`, Then print only the lines with number of fields equal to `n` (`NF==n`).

**Sample:**

```
$ cat File
NAME|ADDRESS|PHONE
Jack|SA|123|aaa|aaaa
JOHN|New York|111-222-3333
Jane|New Jer

$ awk -F\| 'NR==1{n=NF}NF==n' File
NAME|ADDRESS|PHONE
JOHN|New York|111-222-3333
```

Answer (score 1):

Through python3

```
with open('file') as f:
    c = f.readline().count('|')      # read the first line and count the occurance of | symbol and store the count to the variable c
    f.seek(0)                        # get back to the top
    for line in f:                   # iterate over all the lines present in the file.
        if line.count('|') == c:     # count the occurances of | on that particular line and check the count against the variable c
            print(line, end="")      # if both counts are equal then print the corresponding line.
```

**Output:**

```
NAME|ADDRESS|PHONE
JOHN|New York|111-222-3333
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example (did not test it so some syntax errors might remain but you should get the rough idea)

```
 delimiter='|'
 with open(input,'r') as fr:
   with open(output,'w') as fw:
     headers=fr.readline()
     headersCount=len(headers.split(delimiter))
     fw.write(headers)
     for line in fr.readlines():
       if len(line.split(delimiter))==headersCount:
         fw.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Logic is good, syntax and error checking may need work.  Double check

delimiter = '|'
lines = open(file,"r").readlines()
header = lines.pop(0)
print(header)
headerElements = header.count(delimiter)
for data in lines:
  if data.count(delimiter) == headerElements:
    print(data)
```